# register_globals on in PHP5 using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

this is my situation. in my hosting account i have several folders which each folder represents a website. 
in the directory root of my hosting the `php5.ini` has the `register_globals off`. on of them folders in order to work requires the `register_globals on`. i tried to add this line  `php_flag register_globals on` in the `.htaccess` of this folder but without success.  is there any method that makes this folder global on and all the others global off. 
(sorry for my english) thanks

Comment: Likely not. There's a reason shared hosts disable it, and that's because it's extremely exploitable if developed incorrectly. Alternatively, you can attempt to use `import_request_variables()`, but that's likely disabled as well. Instead, you should resolve the vulnerabilities in your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `extract()` function to import global variant. For example:

```
extract($_GET);
extract($_COOKIE);
extract($_POST);
```

But it's **DANGEROUS** if your PHP variants can be controlled by use input.

For example, if you have following code to perform use login in `auth.php`:

```
$authorized = check_user($username, $password);
...
extract($_GET);
...
if($authorized)
    echo "Welcome!admin."
else
    echo "Please log in."
```

Just visit auth.php?authorized=1, then you can bypass the password validation.
That's why PHP defaulty set `register_globals off` in later version.

I recommend upgrading you code to get rid of this problem.